# Should I actually build Cloud Castle in Order campaigns? Why?

Tags: heroes-of-might-and-magic-4

In order to build Cloud Castle and to meet the prerequisites (Citadel and Castle), I need to spend 3 days of building and pay 29.000 gold, 36 wood, 36 ore, 20 gems, plus the Titans themselves aren't free. It takes *time* to build such money up, and there are many more ways to use it -- it referring to both time and money. I can buy more Genies, build my Institute of Magic fully, or, if I find another town, invest in there. By the time when I can afford Titans I most likely already have a handful of Genies and am able to pretty much finish the campaign, I will have to wait for building them, then transport them, then walk with them (they are slower than heroes, hence I do less in one turn).

In a normal game Dragon Golems seem to be worth their money, but... I can't build Dragon Golems in the Order campaign.

**Should I actually try to build the Titans in Order campaigns, or is the money better to be spent on something else?**

Answer (score 3):

Of course, titans are a lvl 4 creature and among the best shooters in the game. They may be expensive, but they certainly are worth the money. Titans and dragon golems are about equal power. Titans have slightly worse stats but are shooters.

Also the price difference really isn't that big. The dwelling itself costs 14k gold for both. Cloud Castle needs 32 common and 20 rare resources. dragon golem factory needs 40 common and 16 rare resources.

Cloud castle needs castle, which costs 15000 and 40 common resources total.
Dragon golem factory needs university and alchemist shop which clocks in at 8750 gold, 18 common and 8 rare resources. So, you save around 6000 gold and a handful of resoruces and get more useful buildings by going for dragon golems.

Titan vs dragon golem is a matchup, where it is a good idea to build both in equal numbers.

Comment: No-no-no, you didn't understand me! I clarified the question. I ask if Titans are actually worth their money in *Order campaigns*, where you fight the dumb AI anyway, and fast advancement of Genies isn't stopped by a clever player, where you can't build Dragon Golems until further in the game, etc. Of course, against a real player rushing lvl 4 is a must (though I like Dragon Golems anyway).

Comment: I don't see how that affects my answer. titans are still worth it, of course. You may be able to do the campaign without them, but that naturally depends on your chosen difficulty, your playstyle and your personal skill level. Titans will make it easier, if you choose to explore the maps thoroughly. If you are the type of player to rush through as quickly as possible, you may be better off not investing in them.